# Unit tests failing in Jenkins

Tags: c#, unit-testing, jenkins

We have 10K+ unit tests in C# solution which are passed when running in local and in TFS.

Now, we are setting up Jenkins for our solution stack and we are facing issue of around 250 Unitests failing consistently.

The same unit tests are passed when i tried running them in jenkins setup server by using Visual Studio and Commnad prompt(MSTest).

What do you think is the issue? Any leads to look at this issue will be helpful.

**Edit 1:**

I did the research and not able to find anything as the problem itself is strange one. If you are not clear please raise questions instead of Down voting.

**Edit 2:**

I am able to find out the issue. It is with the unittests dll config file. When i executed MSTest in server by removing the config file, i am seeing same set of tests failing which are failing with Jenkins setup.

I guess we need to modify the steps configure in Jenkins portal to load the unittests dll config file.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you have tests that are not actually Unit tests, but instead are integration tests or worse, and they fail non-deterministically.  Other than that, you're asking people to do the impossible here without source code posted.

Either post source, or hire a consultant who knows about Jenkins IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sure these are unittests, i need to see why they are failing.

Answer (score 0):

There might be issues with conditional compilation symbols (e.g. `DEBUG` vs. `RELEASE` code): in VS you normally run the tests on a DEBUG build, on the CI server on a release build.

Also look at some global state not being cleaned up correctly. Some threads which may still be running after a test has seemingly finished may corrupt later tests even when those later tests are located in a different test dll. That can sometimes be detected if test failure depends on the order of tests run.

Another issue often faced is dependency on test data in files: the files may be missing in the virtualized environment where the test is actually run. Use the `Deployment` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/). Maybe you can check in VS your "Build"-tag the Platform target. It should be the same like Jenkins is configured. For example "Platform target" is x64, it should be used in Jenkins as well.